# Keep form size when moving, if changed from another thread?

Tags: winforms, user-interface

By experiment I found that Resize event is fired when Move is performed. Not only that, but  Move action also preserves resize factors (so literally Move=Resize). In practice it means, when the form is being Moved (i.e. by user), and if another thread resizes it through BeginInvoke, it will get its original size (the one it had before movement started) when the next Move event happens.

Business use case/example: user opens a screen with dynamically sized ListBox, which contains dynamic list of items, whose population may take considerable time. Assuming loading takes place in a parallel thread and then BeginInvoke is called to update DataSource. When DataSource is updated, form size should change to accommodate all items on screen, if possible (if not, pagination will occur). With default approach, size update will have no effect if user was moving the form across the screen (to another screen would be best example) when the list finished loading, as it would automatically revert to original size.

Question: is it possible to somehow override Move or Resize behavior to consume that new size and not revert to the original one? Should I look into WndProc hacking?

Comment: My advice would be to forget about doing that, and just never resize your form programmatically. That's for the user to do. And try to remember the size that the user selected. That's the expected behavior, and no user will blame you if you do not resize your form to fit the data. Personally, I find it very annoying when software tries to play clever with me in ways like this.

Comment: @Mike: Thanks for your reply. Problem is it being a generic pick list/selector, which may contain 1 item, and there may also be over 200, depending on the context. With 200 items it almost occupies the whole screen. Now in contrast, imagine a plain white screen with 1 lonely item on it - certainly would not look cool. Based on your ideas, here is a workaround: when user is moving the form, don't resize automatically. Instead, have an option of manual size-to-fit on the form (i.e. a button), and have the user do it. Not the ultimate solution, but is definitely better than my current approach.

Comment: Well, the thing is, people expect a certain behavior from applications, and applications that don't exhibit this behavior are perceived as bizarre. I mean, look at windows explorer: it does not resize itself when you open up a folder with just one file, does it? People are used to this kind of behavior, that's what they consider normal. The "size to fit" button is a very good idea.

Comment: @Mike: Good points overall. But explorer is a bit different, since at any moment same screen may contain different amount of items. Even better, number of items changes as you work through them. With this pick list being a dialog = volatile form, that only needs to live until user makes selection. So here goes the question about productivity. If you prefer to see as many items as possible and you also want to see as much of your other screen real estate as possible, all at the same time (maybe it helps you make a right pick), would you NOT want this dialog to be automatically resized-to-fit?

Comment: @Neolisk: I'd like to see your solution to this. I have a Splash Screen that I am supposed to make grow out of the Start Menu to it's designed size on the Center Screen. I tried using the `ResizeBegin` and `ResizeEnd` methods presented below, but they never fire.

Comment: @jp2code: Dunno if it is possible to attach anything into a comment, so I published the solution to my blog (with source code). See this link: http://www.neolisk.com/techblog/vbnet-delay-form-resize-to-fit-until-it-finished-loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if my answer would be useful 3 months late, but I got around this by handling the `Form.ResizeBegin` and `Form.ResizeEnd` events. These are called respectively whenever the user starts and stops dragging around the form on the screen.

In ResizeBegin event handler

```
beingMoved=true;
```

In the method called by BeginInvoke:

```
if(beingMoved)
    needsExplicitSizing=true;
```

In ResizeEnd event handler:

```
beingMoved=false;
if(needsExplicitSizing)
    this.Size = new Size(width,height);
```

Comment: I sort of came to the same solution, with a slightly different approach. The baseline is that you postpone this size change until it can be safely processed. There are more caveats to it, but I'll mark your post as an answer, since the question does not have one. Thanks.