# Changes to Form.Size do not take effect when form is being moved

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a simple `System.Windows.Forms.Form`.
Based on business requirements, once certain functionality becomes available as a result of some background processing, I am increasing the form's size and opening up a previously hidden area with additional controls (buttons etc). The changes to the form's size are done by a background thread, using `BeginInvoke`.

All this works fine. However, if the user is dragging around the form on the screen, and coincidentally during this time the method that changes form's size is called, the size change does *not* become effective (technically, the form changes size, but instantaneously reverts to the previous size).

I am changing the form size by setting the `Form.Size` property, but have tried other ways like setting `Form.ClientSize`, and calling `Form.SetBounds()`. Have also tried out `Form.SuspendLayout()`/`Form.ResumeLayout()` and forcing `Form.PerformLayout()`.

Nothing I have tried so far works, and when it is being moved around, the form refuses to change size.

Comment: You would have to prevent to user from resizing the window.  Nothing that's visible in the question.  Post code that reproduces this problem.   A more sane approach is to use a panel's Visible property instead.

Comment: Actually the user is moving the window, not resizing it (they cannot resize). The resize happens programmatically.I can use Panels and set/reset visibility, but then when a panel is invisible, there's just a whole lot of empty space on the form that doesn't look all that great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put code in the Form_LocationChanged event to detect if the previously hidden area is visible (or should be via a bool variable) and resize the form accordingly. Otherwise the ResizeEnd event fires after a move ends, try that.

Comment: Thanks, I actually did come across another question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733018/keep-form-size-when-moving-if-changed-from-another-thread) in which I got to know that form move = form resize, and that way arrived on handling ResizeEnd in our application.